# My virtual hosts set up always redirect to /xampp Im using fedora 23 and xampp 1.8.2-6

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, vhosts, hosts, fedora-23

My virtual hosts is always redirecting to /xampp page im using fedora 23 and xampp 1.8.2-6.

here is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.0.1 test.dev.ph
```

While my /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.dev.ph
DocumentRoot /var/www/projects/test/www/
<Directory "/var/www/projects/test/www/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Required all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after editing the hosts and vhost I restart my lampp by "sudo sh lampp restart" and all runs fine. I also try to put my files in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/ and changes everything in vhosts but I still have the same error.

If I put this in web "http://test.dev.ph/projects/test/www/" It was right

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the "Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" should un-comment or added in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf and then restart the computer